# How to parse a JSON into a map with variable type in Golang

Tags: json, go, go-map

I have the following JSON response from the Salt-Stack API:

```
{
    "return": [{
        "<UUID1>": true,
        "<UUID2>": "Minion did not return. [No response]",
        "<UUID3>": true,
        "<UUID4>": false
    }]
}
```

I usually use a map structure to unmarshall it in Go:

```
type getMinionsStatusResponse struct {
    Returns     []map[string]bool `json:"return"`
}
```

But due to the second row where an error response is returned (in string format) instead of the boolean, I got the following error: `json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type bool`

I wonder how I can marshall this JSON format in Golang using the `encoding/json` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unmarshalling dynamic json where output is different use interface to unmarshal the same. It will unmarshal whole json as it is structured with any type inside it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    jsonbytes := []byte(`{
        "return": [{
            "<UUID1>": true,
            "<UUID2>": "Minion did not return. [No response]",
            "<UUID3>": true,
            "<UUID4>": false
            }]
    }`)
    var v interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonbytes, &v); err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rMdXrYZ5Kyo)

Comment: Can I use `interface` for the map value only? because everything else is fixed except the map value type.

Comment: yes you can do that too. But this is an array you will have to use unmarshaller interface for dynamic values in json